# Is it easier to slow something down in special relativity than to speed it up?

Tags: special-relativity

I never really thought about the different cause and effects of interacting with an object moving at relativistic speeds. My quick intuition would have had me guessing that no matter which direction I hit this object I would get the same outcome, upon further thinking about this I believe that there can be a significant difference in outcomes depending on the direction the object is hit in. I think the answer to this is fairly straightforward (its harder to move something closer to the speed of light than it is to slow it down) but I would like a second opinion on my thoughts on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bear in mind the following points...

All motion is relative, so an object that is slowing down in one frame of reference may be speeding up in another.

It therefore follows that KE is frame dependent.

If an object is stationary relative to you and then you hit it, the resulting gain of speed by the object, relative to you, will be the same regardless of which direction you hit it in.

However, for a passing observer, the change in speed will depend on direction. Specifically, if the observer is moving to the right, and you hit the object to the left, the speed of the object will increase relative to the passing observer, but if you hit it to the right, the speed of the object will decrease relative to the passing observer.

Finally, if you hit the object so that it gains a speed v compared to you, then to a passing observer, the effect of that change of speed has to be calculated using the relativistic law of velocity addition, which will result in a bigger change if the speed of the object is to be subtracted from the observers speed than if the speed of the object is to be added.

Overall, then, it means that a given hit in the object's rest frame leads to a given acceleration of the object regardless of the direction of the hit. However, in any other frame the effect depends on direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving in a rocket at 290000 km/s, it is just as hard as always to accelerate or decelerate one km/s relative to your current system. That is the whole point about relativity: you can always add or subtract one km/s (if you have the energy), but that does not mean you can exceed the speed of light as seen from the observer who sees you already moving at close to light speed. For you as the comoving observer, however, moving that close to the speed of light feels in no way special, you can do everything that you could do here on earth, just as fine as always. And especially direction independent, because you always feel yourself at rest (unless, of course, you look out of the window, which is not a dynamic effect).